# I.cloud email address

Tags: ipad

I created an i.cloud email address quite some time ago but never used it. I now can’t remember what it was. Is there a way to find it please?

Comment: How would anyone including Apple know it is yours and not one you are trying to steal?

Comment: Apple knows your email address if it was icloud.com or me.com and was created on the apple website.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apple account, you can logon and your email accounts will be listed under the column named "Reachable at". If you don't have an Apple account you can go to https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin and create a free account. To login go to same link.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201354:

> You can also look up your Apple ID by entering the full name and email address associated with your Apple ID.

Also:

> From your Apple ID account page
>
> 1. Go to your Apple ID account page and click Forgot Apple ID or password.
> 2. When you're asked to enter your Apple ID, click If you forgot your Apple ID, you can look it up.
> 3. Enter your first name, last name, and email address. If you enter the wrong email address, you can try again with a different one.
>
> If your mobile number is your Apple ID, these steps won't work.